# Can I use an ST62T10C6 MCU as an audio amplifier?

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier

Can I use an ST62T10C6 MCU as an audio amplifier?
E.g. as a substitute for a LM386?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, no.

An audio amplifier can do two things (often both at the same time).

1. Increase the amplitude of the input signal
2. Increase the available power of the signal (by decreasing the output impedance)

The st62t10c6 has an ADC, so you could sample the input signal, and then you could maybe PWM the output to approximate this input signal, but the signal would be pretty crap since the ADC can only do 14kHz. This makes it a bad amplitude-amplifier. Also, the st62t10c6 has basically no drive strength, so it is a bad power-amplifier.